# Why is MapReduce Map memory greater than the Block size on cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

In Hadoop Yarn below are the observations:

a) For each InputSplit or block a new map will be triggered.

b) Typical Block size for a cluster would be 128 MB.

c) The MapReduce.map.memory.mb would be configured greater than 1 GB in most of the clusters.

In fact Cloudera recommendation for block size is 128 MB and MapReduce.map.memory.mb is 1 GB

When the block size is only 128 MB, why do we need to allocate 1 GB to the map memory (MapReduce.map.memory.mb)? Ideally 128 MB should satisfy the need at most. Why is that we are even giving more than the block size for the map memory?

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce does not load the full 128 mb input block into memory at all since it should be streaming the data through your map function.

It however has some output and spill buffers and sorting buffers that need to be maintained and they are quite big (upwards of 64mb, the default for `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb` is 100mb).

Also your own map processing logic might need to have memory associated- eg for additional resources that are loaded from elsewhere. After all, 1gb is a safe default and it is not necessarily tied to the input block size.

The framework overhead, discounting the spill buffers allocated, is super small (< 50mb).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the explanation. It makes sense that the memory is needed for output, spill buffers and sorting buffers. As the output, spill buffers and sorting buffers are from the data coming from the map function which runs on block of 128 MB, if my block size is 256 MB, I expect to have more memory assigned to MapReduce.map.memory.mb ?

Comment: @Premchand I would not expect to change the heap memory of a mapper based on input block size.

Answer (score 0):

Each container (where the mappers are running) is running on separate JVM. The `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` reflects all the total space required for container: Heap, Stack, etc. So in addition to loading those 128MB of block size for processing, other JVM related processes must be managed, thus it requires more memory.